# Facebook Customer Chat plugin not showing on Android phone Chrome mobile browser

Tags: android, html, facebook, plugins, chat

I managed to implement FB Customer Chat plugin into my website https://ts.malta4u.org/chat. However plugin is showing only on PC Chrome browser and on mobile it is not. Is there some settings that I missed for enabling/disabling plugin on different platforms?
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
already implemented in `<head>` tag

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v7.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"   page_id="100772778373309" logged_in_greeting="Hi! How can we help you?" logged_out_greeting="Hi! How can we help you?" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too.  The facebook messenger only worked in Chrome but did not work in Safari or on any of the mobile platforms.  The thing that solved it for me was turning off the "Country Restrictions" on the facebook page.